# MVC Application completely ignores forms authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've spent the last 3 days reading through every article I could find and trying to troubleshoot this issue based on those articles but I'm not getting anywhere. This seems like it should be a simple thing that should just "work" but it is not. Basically, I set my forms authentication timeout in the web.config file. I log into our site and do not do anything for the entire timeout period (set to 1 minute now for testing). I click a link that requires the user to be logged in and would expect to be sent back to the login page, however the page is served just fine like nothing happened. The value of User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still True. Shouldn't the user be logged out and this value get set to false upon forms authentication timing out??

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: There is no "relevant code". The question at the point it was asked only has web.config settings which are clearly communicated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the code when the user was logging in we were overriding the settings in the web.config. When we were creating the new FormsAuthenticationTicket we were specifying a timeout much greater than was specified in the config. Problem solved. :-)